# How does a double-precision floating value change its value when switched from x86 platform to x64 build?

Tags: .net, floating-point, 64-bit, precision

**Observation:**

[image]

**Environment:**
VS2017, x64 platform

**EDIT:** <s>A double-precision floating variable has stored a value `1.3377`.</s>

I am trying to store a value '1.3377' in a double-precision floating variable. When built with `x86` platform the value remains same, but the stored value change when built with `x64` platform. I know floating point arithmetic can be tricky and floating-point calculations have rounding error anyway, the question is:

> How this stored value change when the platform is changed from `x86` to `x64`?

I have done some basic research and read how floating point values are stored, but I am confused 'how' different platform affects this representation.

Comment: "A double-precision floating variable has stored a value `1.3377`" - no it hasn't, that *isn't a possible value* in double-precision numbers. If you want to store the exact value `1.3377`, use `decimal` - but know that it will be larger and slower.

Comment: Hmm, no, this doesn't have anything to do with storage.  Look at the return value of BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d).  Should be 4608703284394180424.  If it is not then you have a problem with the compiler.  It if is in both flavors then you have a problem with external code corrupting the processor's rounding mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. `double` (`System.Double`) is 64 bits on both, and the same IEEE representation is used either way. Note that not all numbers can be represented in IEEE floating point, so it is not surprising that `1.3377` gets approximated to something close... *everything* gets approximated to something close, unless it is an integer or just a really lucky coincidence. This doesn't change between x86 and x64. The only difference is possible post-JIT op-codes to manipulate the values (loading in 2 operations rather than 1, for example)

Comment: If I remember correctly, double math is done using the old x87 instructions on x86, that internally support 80 bits, while it uses SSE(something) on x64 that is pure 64 bits.

Comment: @xanatos which would be the post-JIT opcodes part; however, that doesn't change anything that seems hinted at in the question